# Repeatition of html tags while including a file in php

Tags: php, html, strip-tags

I am including fetch_header.php in header.php
When I included a file, code is working properly.
But when I checked html tags by pressing Ctrl+U, it is giving me structure like as further:

```
<html>
  <title>//tile of fetch_header.php</tile>
  <head>//head of fetch_header.php</head>
  <body>//body of fetch_header.php</body>
</html>
<html>
  <title>//tile of header.php.php</tile>
  <head>//head of header.php.php</head>
  <body>//body of header.php.php</body>
</html>
```

html tags are repeating. How to overcome on this issue.?

```
<?php global $theme; ?><!DOCTYPE html>
<?php 


include_once "fetch_header.php";


function wp_initialize_the_theme() { if (!function_exists("wp_initialize_the_theme_load") || !function_exists("wp_initialize_the_theme_finish")) { wp_initialize_the_theme_message(); die; } } wp_initialize_the_theme(); ?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="<?php bloginfo('html_type'); ?>; charset=<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>" />
<title><?php $theme->meta_title(); ?></title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

<?php $theme->hook('meta'); ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo THEMATER_URL; ?>/css/reset.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo THEMATER_URL; ?>/css/defaults.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" />
<!--[if lt IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php /*echo THEMATER_URL*/; ?>/css/ie.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" /><![endif]-->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" />

<?php if ( is_singular() ) { wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' ); } ?>
<?php  wp_head(); ?>
<?php $theme->hook('head'); ?>
<!-- bxSlider Javascript file -->
<script src="<?php echo THEMATER_URL; ?>/bxslider/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
<!-- bxSlider CSS file -->
<link href="<?php echo THEMATER_URL; ?>/bxslider/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700,500' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo THEMATER_URL; ?>/css/custom.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" />

</head>
<center id="headerF">

</center>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery.noConflict();
    </script>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>


<?php $theme->hook('html_before'); ?>
<div id="container">

    <?php if($theme->display('menu_primary')) { ?>
        <div class="clearfix">
            <?php $theme->hook('menu_primary'); ?>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>

    <?php if($theme->display('menu_secondary')) { ?>
        <div class="clearfix">
            <?php $theme->hook('menu_secondary'); ?>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Can you post the php code generating the result?

Comment: Use `include_once()` instead of `include()`

Comment: @JBC Sorry to say but i can not post the code.

Comment: @Shankar Tried with your suggestion but still problem is same.

Comment: Am sorry we can't help if you can't post the code as your question will be closed under .. This question appears to be off-topic **because it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem.** Describe your problem in more detail or include a minimal example in the question itself.

Comment: @Shankar Check the code now

Comment: looks like you won't need to include `fetch_header.php` you are already outputting the header in the code starting at line `<html xmlns= ....` so if you include the `fetch_header.php` even with `include_once` you are going to get duplicate if it also outputs the header.

Comment: @bansi ok, fine, I can remove <head> part, but what about <title> and <html> tags? 
I can not edit <title> in fetch_header.php and I want my own title in header.php

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran have you got any solution with my code? Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have edited code as further :

```
<?php global $theme; ?><!DOCTYPE html>

<?php  function wp_initialize_the_theme() { if (!function_exists("wp_initialize_the_theme_load") || !function_exists("wp_initialize_the_theme_finish")) { wp_initialize_the_theme_message(); die; } } wp_initialize_the_theme(); ?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="<?php bloginfo('html_type'); ?>; charset=<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>" />
<title><?php $theme->meta_title(); ?></title>
<?php

 $data = file_get_contents('http://cgi.ebay.in/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?GlobalHeader&headertype=FULL:HOMEPAGE');

// require_once "fetch_header.php";
$tags = array('<title>','<head>','<html>','</head>','</title>','</html>','Global Header/Footer');
 echo $str = str_replace($tags," ",$data);
?>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Use   `include_once "fetch_header.php";`

replace all `include"fetch_header.php" to`include_once "fetch_header.php"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
require_once("fetch_header.php");
```